# Swift - How To Save Image Button?

Tags: swift

How to save On-Off value of a button? I have a On-Off button, when a user opens the app and click the Off button, I want the app to save it, so that when the app is reopened, the value of the button is still Off. Hopefully, this can be done by using `User Defaults`. My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var soundEnable:Bool = true
    var soundImage:UIImage?

    @IBAction func soundbtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let soundButton = sender

        if (soundEnable) {
            soundImage = UIImage.init(named: "mute.png")
            soundEnable = false
        } else {
            soundImage = UIImage.init(named: "sound.png")
            soundEnable = true
        }

        soundButton.setImage(soundImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

[image: See image]

Comment: You want to when app is closed and then you come back then it should show selected image? or you want on change on click action?

Comment: @Dharmbir Singh I want it show selected image. Thanks!

Comment: lly then see my edited answer.

Comment: @JackIly Please check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Please write these lines in `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (UserDefaultsManager.useDarkTheme) {
        soundImage = UIImage.init(named: "mute")
        print(UserDefaultsManager.useDarkTheme)

} else {
      soundImage = UIImage.init(named: "sound")
      print(UserDefaultsManager.useDarkTheme)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't copy answer from some one else answer, You have just edit your answer from my one

Comment: @NiravD See my comment above, i have edited after confiming his concern. It's not copy paste, even i've ginen answer before 25 mins.

Comment: @Dharmbir Singh I use swift 3, Bool value inside `.set(value:Bool, forKey: String)`

Comment: @JackIly Yes, i have changed my answer after your concern.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh Then you need to post answer like that also OP already using  `set(bool:forKey)` as of it is Swift 3 Syntax changed

Comment: @DharmbirSingh I doesn't taking about any vote or fight the issue is you have edit your answer with copy of my one that I have posted after it don't you think it is wrong

Comment: @NiravD Keep calm bro (y)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to set the image one more place at viewDidLoad.
2. You input the wrong parameter for setImage:

   soundButton.setImage(soundImage, for: UIControlState())

it should be a specific state:

```
soundButton.setImage(soundImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Thanks your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

let ImageNameKey = "ImageNameKey"

let soundbg = UIImage(named: "sound")
let mutebg = UIImage(named: "mute")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Sound.play(file: "bg", fileExtension: "wav", numberOfLoops: -1)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let name = defaults.string(forKey: ImageNameKey) {
        if (name == "sound") {
            backgroundImage.image = soundbg
        } else {
            backgroundImage.image = mutebg
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func clickbtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if(backgroundImage.image == soundbg){
        backgroundImage.image = mutebg
        defaults.set("mute", forKey: ImageNameKey)
        Sound.enabled = false
    }
    else{
        backgroundImage.image = soundbg
        defaults.set("sound", forKey: ImageNameKey)
        Sound.enabled = true
    }
}
```